# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' but I have bs4 installed I believe

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, python-3.6

So I am not able to import BeautifulSoup after I have installed `bs4`.

I have tried installing `bs4` using `pip, pip3, and pip3.6`. All successfully install `bs4`, but I still get the error saying there is no module named `bs4` when I try and import it.

I have also tried doing it by using "pip install beautifulsoup4" with no luck.

I am using `python 3.6.5` on `Windows 10`.

[This is the output of my pip commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMQH2.jpg)

Let me know things I can try differently to get this working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of Python installed?

Comment: I don't believe I do.

Comment: Is Python path added to your environment variables?

Comment: I am going to say no for that one as I don't remember ever doing that. I will look up how to do that, do it, and then report back if that fixed it.

Comment: I added the path, but when I tested it it didn't work haha. I added the path in the environment vaiables and then I added that variable %PYTHON_HOME% to the path environment variable.

Comment: I got the environment variable working, but bs4 still not

Answer (score 0):

Had two installs of Python. Man I feel like an idiot haha. The second install was hidden in a visual studio folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - but switched my interpreter (in pycharm) from the 'local' to the global python scripts.

Successful running of script on local html files and on requests.

Thank you to this thread and one other for helping me fix the issue.